# How to Remove an Element from Webpage with No ID, Class?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, removeall

How can I remove an Element from a Webpage, which has No ID or Class.

This is the website :

```
https://www.sentinelassam.com/north-east-india-news/assam-news/40-new-colleges-to-be-set-up-in-btc-assam-minister-himanta-biswa-sarma-516420
```

And the element to remove has a structure like this :

```
<p><b>Also Read <a href="https://www.sentinelassam.com/national-news/iisfs-vigyan-yatra-flagged-off-from-various-indian-cities-516407">IISF's 'Vigyan Yatra' flagged off from various Indian cities</a></b></p>
```

The `Also Read` text is common across the Multiple Occurences on the Webpage. If I can remove one element, then a loop will Remove all of this (I think).

Can this whole element can be removed using the `Also Read` text? I tried to use `decompose()` but where do I apply this `decompose()` method ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Developper tools of Chrome or any other browser. Find the element that you want to remove and then by right clicking on this element choose `Copy > Copy selector`. This will give you a selector like this :

```
#details-page-infinite-scrolling-data > div.article > div.article-text-desc > div > div > p:nth-child(22) > b > a
```

This selector can probably be simplified. Now you can use BeautifulSoup to remove it:

```
selector = "#details-page-infinite-scrolling-data > div.article > div.article-text-desc > div > div > p:nth-child(22) > b > a"
soup.select_one(selector).decompose()
```

I didn't tested it.

Comment: Okay, I will try and let u know

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import  utils, SimplifiedDoc
xml = '''
<p><b>Also Read <a href="https://www.sentinelassam.com/national-news/iisfs-vigyan-yatra-flagged-off-from-various-indian-cities-516407">IISF's 'Vigyan Yatra' flagged off from various Indian cities</a></b></p>
'''

doc  = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
# If you want to remove tag b
b = doc.getElementByText('Also Read', tag='b')
b.remove()
print (doc.html)

doc  = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
# If you want to remove tag p
p = doc.getElementByText('Also Read', tag='p')
p.remove()
print (doc.html)
```